# How to customize the background color of USSD dialog box?

Tags: color, ussd

Most of you are already aware of the dialog that shows up when you dial a service provider code on your smartphone, a perfect example is the code *123#. Is there a way to tweak android to modify the background color of this dialog apart from switching to dark mode? Can I make it blue and the text white?

Comment: The dialog color depends on the Android OS theme, and usually it cannot be customized without rooting the device.

Comment: @AndrewT.M Thanks for your comment, am going to request this feature from Google and see if they will include it in a future version of Android.